# Redirect to WWW if directory and file not found

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've found a few answers but none of them seem to be able to answer my problem.
On my server we use non-www for asset serving and www subdomain is cnamed to our bigcartel store. What I'm trying to do is serve files from the non-www page if file is found, else redirect to the www subdomain with original request.

eg: `redirect domainname.com/product-name` to `www.domainname.com/product-name` because it doesn't exist on our asset server.

I've tried the following; but I've had no luck.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got your logical conditions backwards. You seem to be redirecting when the conditions say: the requested resource is an existing file, or an existing symbolic link, or an existing directory. You want the opposite of that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domainname\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domainname.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```